# Triangle over ImageView with icon that change upon ImageView onClick

Tags: android, android-layout

**First:** I am trying to get the exact as following:
      [image]

i.e triangle at the left corner of ImageView with Icon inside it (selected icon). i this is my code as attempt to get what i want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
        </rotate>
        </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

unfortunately, i am no able to put the icon inside the triangle correctly and this is what i got:

[image]

**Secondly:** how can i change the triangle color and the contained icon upon ImageView onClick event? i.e to something like:

[image]

appreciate your help.